# Wordpress - after upload on server 404 on all pages, no css

Tags: css, wordpress, http-status-code-404

I have developed a wordpress based site using xampp 1.8.3. On my local machine all is wordìking fine. On the server I am using php 5.4.12.

On the server I copied the site on a subfolder name site, wich is the same subfolder name I had in xampp/htdocs. Then i changed all occurances of localhost to mydomain.com with the searchreplacedb2.php script (http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases). I am confident that the tool is working properly and the issue does not depend on it as I have used it several other times with succcess.

Therefore since on my local machine the site was in localhost/site, on the hosting server is on mydomain.com/site.

The proble is that accessing the site home page produces a wordpress managed 404 page with no css being loaded. The title, menu and other site specific text is displayed, therefore the db is being read correctly. Trying to access any page other than the home page gets a webhost managed 404 page. This happens also if I try to access page through non symbolic urls, ei. mydomain.com/site/?page_id=5; therefore it is should not be a redirection issues.

what can be the issue? How can I proceed in troubleshooting it?

Thanks, in advance for your time.

Comment: You might want to try re-uploading the core WordPress files - might have been a glitch where one file got corrupted or missed. If that doesn't work you could share a link to the site, might help us troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to double check everything, first:

- Flush the rewrite rules by visiting settings->permalinks then try your pages. Then try:
- List item login to phpmyadmin for each domain, check out the database... options table... verify the "siteurl", and "home" columns. make sure they match the respective domains. Then try:
- List itemCheck the DNS zone template. Could very well be possible DNS conflicts.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out. Care to explain a but more so I can learn a bit about a Wordpress subfolder installation?

Comment: Simply put, when I updated paths from my local machine to the server's, I mistyped one string which got me into trouble. Fixing that resolved the problem.